# Swift - Updating a UITableView with remote JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

i am trying to access data from a remote json file. When something is typed into the searchbar a new NSURLSessionDataTask is made to access the json file. I have successfully been able to extract all the data i need from the json file, but have not been able to update the table view as soon as the data comes in. To show the data i must either scroll so one cell is not visible on the screen. This will make it so that only that one cell has the correct values in it, alternatively, i can also type in a other letter into the searchable which will generate a new json file, but the data from the previous request is only shown now.

I have tried updating the table view in the main thread but that doesn't seem to make any difference. I have also tried multiple other methods, but still no luck.

Comment: try to call table.reloadData() when you have data come in ?
"I have tried updating the table view in the main thread but that doesn't seem to make any difference. I have also tried multiple other methods, but still no luck." what exactly did you try to update tableview ?

Comment: you have to post your code and let us see

Comment: You can try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45048237/how-get-json-data-in-swift-and-add-it-to-url/45048494#45048494

Comment: you can try this: - Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45048237/how-get-json-data-in-swift-and-add-it-to-url/45048494#45048494

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
          if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["loginNodes"].arrayObject {
                self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
            }

            if self.arrRes.count > 0 {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
```

Note :arrRes is the name of array.

- complete details are :[How get JSON Data in Swift and add it to URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45048237/how-get-json-data-in-swift-and-add-it-to-url/45048494#45048494)

Answer (score 0):

To get the best answer you'll want to post code, specifics, and maybe even a link to the full project, but based on what you are saying the data is loaded in the code properly and is not being refreshed in the table view.

To fix this you first need a reference to the table view that is not loading, for this example I'll call it `tableView`. Then you can force it to reload all the visible data by calling

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

After your JSON data has finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

When your data is loaded successfully just call

```
self.table.reloadData()
```

What it will do is it will populate the cells again with the updated data.