# How get JSON Data in Swift and add it to URL

Tags: ios, json, swift

How I Get JSON Data and add it to URL?

My Case is I Will access JSON URL, but i need value Token from other JSON URL.

This My Json, i need a token to access it.
**https://api-sandbox.tiket.com/flight_api/all_airport/token=......**

To get token, i must access from other JSON, this view the other JSON to get token.

{
"diagnostic":{"status":200,"elapsetime":"0.2082","memoryusage":"16.99MB","unix_timestamp":1499832598,"confirm":"success","lang":"id","currency":"IDR"},
"output_type":"json",
"login_status":"false",
"token":"**b650fce732668b58b0a4c404b65932e972ad123d**"
}

I must get value token, and add it to first JSON URL to access First JSON

This my coding :

func getLatestKotaTujuan() {

```
    var tujuanUrl = URLComponents(string: "https://api-sandbox.tiket.com/flight_api/all_airport?")!
    tujuanUrl.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "token", value: "4d4bba355bb920fbdc1aa3848769a59ba74ea03c" ),
        URLQueryItem(name: "output", value: "json")
    ]

    let request = tujuanUrl.url
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        // Parse JSON data
        if let data = data {
            self.kotaTujuan = self.parseJsonData(data: data)

            // Reload table view
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Alamofire & SwiftyJSON

1. Install two cocopod

   ```
      pod 'Alamofire'
      pod 'SwiftyJSON'
   ```
2. My Json is look like

   ```
   {"loginNodes":[{"errorMessage":"Welcome To Alamofire","name":Enamul Haque,"errorCode":"0","photo":null}]}
   ```
3. Declare multidimensional array

   ```
    var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]()
   ```
4. Alamofire get json from server

   ```
    func getList() {


      Alamofire.request("url.....", method: .post, parameters: [
       "userNameid":"25"

       ]).responseJSON{(responseData) -> Void in
           if((responseData.result.value != nil)){

               // let jsonData = JSON(responseData.result.value)
               HUD.hide();

               if((responseData.result.value != nil)){
                   let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

                   if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["loginNodes"].arrayObject {
                       self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                   }

                   if self.arrRes.count > 0 {
                       self.tableView.reloadData()
                   }

               }
           }
        }

     }
   ```
5. set data to table view using like

   ```
      override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

       return arrRes.count
   }



     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Agent_Account_Balance_Cell

           cell.namelabel.text = arrRes[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String

          return cell
        }
   ```